# Is there anyway to create alias on query search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create an alias on top of this. Index - test, Type - type

```
POST /test/type/_search
{
    "query": {
    "match": {
        "brand_name": "xyz"
        }
   }    
}
```

But I don't see anyway of doing it,since Elasticsearch aliases can only be created on filters and when I try with term filter,I don't get the results which I want.Any trick to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [query filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html) to use any query as a filter:

```
"filter" : {
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "brand_name" : "xyz"
    }
  }
}
```